# Is getting an IP address with JavaScript as accurate as getting it through PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, http

I'm just wondering, is using JavaScript to get an IP like described in [How to get client's IP address using javascript only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript) just as accurate as using

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

in PHP or another server-side language? What is the different in how the information is extracted in each?

For some background information, I know that Google Analytics is JS code and supposedly I can filter out IPs in my GA dashboard and I'm wondering how that is done and if it's reliable.

Comment: What IP address are you interested in getting, and in what context (browser or Node.js or something else)?

Comment: @Pointy The IP that made the request to the page

Comment: So, the IP of the client browser itself?

Comment: With only JavaScript, you won't be able to get the proper IP. Most people are sitting behind a router, so evenn if there was a way to get the NIC's IP, you would still only get the internal IP (like: 192.168.1.xxx or similar). The NIC doesn't know, or care, about the external IP.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** truly get an IP with JavaScript. All the examples on the page you listed get it from a server or API. PHP is your best option aside from using an existing API. Either way, it's not going to be extremely reliable and can easily be faked.

Comment: What does Google Analytics do, then?

Comment: @SubparWebDev it makes HTTP requests to Google, and each of those requests has a visible IP address at the server. The server code can then return that to the JavaScript in the client.

Comment: GA isn't getting the IP through JavaScript. It is loading files from googles servers. Then they can see the request-ip and set cookies.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** You cannot trust JavaScript for critical information.

The best way to get an IP address with PHP is:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Using 'REMOTE_ADDR' returns the **actual physical IP address** of the client.

---

Depending on your application requirements, it is sometimes helpful to get a client ip that is behinda proxy. You can use the following variable:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

It is important to note however that 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' can be easily spoofed.

---

Google Analytical uses JavaScript to get client PC details like:

1. Screen size and resolution
2. Is mobile device?
3. Java & Flash version
4. Language (Browser)
5. User Agent
6. Operating System

It is important to remember that all this information can be spoofed. However, if a genuine visitor is visiting your website it is very unlikely that this information will return false information.

Comment: Or `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` if the server is behind a proxy and is setting this header.

Comment: Yes, however, it is important to remember that it can be spoofed as it is an HTTP header.

Comment: That's true. that goes for `REMOTE_ADDR` as well. IP-spoofing, it's called ;-)

Comment: Yes. However, to spoof REMOTE_ADDR you must change it at the network level which requires you to have and significant resources ie: access to the network equipment. HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is an actual HTTP header that anyone can change.

Comment: Yes. It's much harder to spoof REMOTE_ADDR. But if you need the client IP you should always check for HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR as well (if your code might end up behind a proxy, that is), otherwise it will look like all calls are comming from one (the proxys) IP. Which they theoretically are. Learned that the hard way once. :)

Comment: Yes that is correct. However, checking the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR really depends on your business requirements. Sometimes, due to enterprise security policies, it is not allowed.